# How to change interface/add buttons on case detail page

Tags: custom-button, case

I am using cases in salesforce and there are different sections on the case layout. Let's call them A, B, C that has some fields. Since there is a lot of data on case detail page. What I want is that when user clicks on any particular case, it should show two buttons. Upon clicking the first button some of the case data is visible and upon clicking the second button, the remaining case data is shown. This would avoid long scrolling on case detail page to see data and look for the desired sections. Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: Classic or lightning?

Comment: I am doing it in lightning

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to collapse the section based upon click of a button.

1. Your user can click on the section to close the sections if not required. No. of clicks will be the same.

If you are looking to implement the buttons for this. you'll need to use Visualforce.  I highly recommend against this unless you absolutely must have this functionality, because as a developer these sort of things take a surprisingly large amount of customization and will create extra maintenance in your Org.

Comment: ok gotcha. So is there a way to keep the sections close by default and once the user expands it opens?

Comment: is there a way to automatically collapse the sections when the user goes to the page for the first time?

Comment: Nope. I don't think there is any such option in standard page layout.